# Flutter: "Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I've made a Flutter Web App 9 months ago, and today when i open the code again to fix an issue i can't run it on web.

I've updated Flutter/Dart version and all the package dependencies.

When i try to run it on Web i get this errors related with 'allowInterop' method:

```
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:73:23: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Firestore'.
 - 'Firestore' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var nextWrapper = allowInterop((Object? noValue) {
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:100:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Firestore'.
 - 'Firestore' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var updateFunctionWrap = allowInterop((transaction) =>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:178:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'LoadBundleTask'.
 - 'LoadBundleTask' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((firestore_interop.LoadBundleTaskProgressJsImpl data) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:188:21: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'LoadBundleTask'.
 - 'LoadBundleTask' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      jsObject.then(allowInterop((value) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:190:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'LoadBundleTask'.
 - 'LoadBundleTask' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      }), allowInterop((error) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:331:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firestore_interop.DocumentSnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:335:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:420:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firestore_interop.QuerySnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:423:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart:626:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_web/src/interop/firestore.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((s) => callback(DocumentSnapshot.getInstance(s)));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart:378:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase_auth_web/src/interop/auth.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((auth_interop.UserJsImpl? user) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart:382:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase_auth_web/src/interop/auth.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController!.addError(e));
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart:417:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase_auth_web/src/interop/auth.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((auth_interop.UserJsImpl? user) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart:422:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase_auth_web/src/interop/auth.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-5.1.3/lib/src/interop/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((e) => _idTokenChangedController!.addError(e));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-3.2.8/lib/src/interop/messaging.dart:64:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging_web/src/interop/messaging.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-3.2.8/lib/src/interop/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-3.2.8/lib/src/interop/messaging.dart:67:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging_web/src/interop/messaging.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-3.2.8/lib/src/interop/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:48:14: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    getPath: allowInterop(strategy.getPath),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:49:15: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    getState: allowInterop(strategy.getState),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:50:26: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    addPopStateListener: allowInterop(strategy.addPopStateListener),
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:51:25: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    prepareExternalUrl: allowInterop(strategy.prepareExternalUrl),
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:52:16: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    pushState: allowInterop(strategy.pushState),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:53:19: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    replaceState: allowInterop(strategy.replaceState),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:54:9: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    go: allowInterop(strategy.go),
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-2.0.1/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:89:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-2.0.1/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:124:27: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
  return PromiseJsImpl<S>(allowInterop((
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.0/lib/src/interop/utils/utils.dart:69:14: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
      return allowInterop(object);
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

My 'Flutter doctor -v':

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-PT)
    • Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at /Users/tiago/Code/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (13 days ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
    • Engine revision 8f2221fbef
    • Dart version 2.18.5
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tiago/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/tiago/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.121

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

check class were duplicate the packages import'package:firebase/firestore.dart'; replaces this with import'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).